# What does $\frac{3x^2 + 2ax + b}{2y} \quad$ mean w.r.t the derivative of $y^2 = x^3 + ax^2 + bx$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

We know that if the given equation were $\quad y = x^3 + ax^2 + bx$, $\quad$ then the derivative would be $3x^2 + 2ax + b$.

Since the given equation is different so the derivative will be: $$2(x^3 + ax^2 + bx)(3x^2 + 2ax + b) \implies 2y(3x^2 + 2ax + b)$$

What does: $$\frac{3x^2 + 2ax + b}{2y}$$
mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pretend that $y$ is a bona fide function of $x$ (it will be near most points on this curve), you can find the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ using [implicit differentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function#Implicit_differentiation). Remember the chain rule: $\frac{d}{dx} f(g(x)) = f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$. That's what we'll do to find $\frac{dy}{dx} = y'(x)$ for the above equation.
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\left[y(x)^2\right] &= \frac{d}{dx}\left[x^3 + ax^2 + bx\right]\\
\frac{d}{dx}\left[x^3 + ax^2 + bx\right] &= 3x^2 + 2ax + b\\
\frac{d}{dx}\left[y(x)^2\right] &= 2y(x)\cdot y'(x) = 2y\frac{dy}{dx}\\
\end{align*}
Putting all this together,
$$
2y\frac{dy}{dx} = 3x^2 + 2ax + b.
$$
Now, as long as $y$ isn't $0$, we can divide both sides by $2y$ to find
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{3x^2 + 2ax + b}{2y}.
$$

What this equation is really telling you is that if you have a point $p = (x_0,y_0)$ such that $y_0^2 = x_0^3 + ax_0^2 + bx_0$ AND $y_0\neq 0$, then the slope of the curve defined by $y^2 = x^3 + ax^2 + bx$ at the point $p$ is $\frac{3x_0^2 + 2ax_0 + b}{2y_0}$.

Comment: The function is hiding like a spooky secret.

Answer (score 1):

This is using implicit derivative. e.g. if we have:$$y^2=3x^2$$and we perform implicit derivative, we would get:$$2y\frac{dy}{dx}=6x$$$$\therefore \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{6x}{2y}=\frac{3x}{y}$$
This is achieved by initially differentiating both sides w.r.t $x$ as follows:$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(y^2\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(3x^2\right)=6x$$and then using the chain rule on the left-hand-side to get:$$\frac{d}{dy}\left(y^2\right)\frac{dy}{dx}=6x$$$$\therefore 2y\frac{dy}{dx}=6x$$